# Dropping insignificant interactions

Tags: regression, interaction

I have two general questions regarding interactions in a Cox regression.

1. I have a hypothesis that marker X has different effect in groups G. The interaction self and the marker are insignificant. When the interaction is dropped, the effect of a marker is significant. How legitimate is it in statistics in general to drop the interaction, just to show that the marker is overall a significant predictor of an outcome?
2. Study participants are grouped according to other variables into groups (G). For example, when A or B is true, they are group 1, C or D they are group 2 and E, F group 3.
   In the model I've left out the variables A-F. When the interaction with G is dropped, the marker overall is significant, however there is strong evidence that marker has different effect depending on A. Can one include both interactions in a model (with A and G)? Or is it advised to build a completely new model with A-F and without Group variable?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Separate questions should be posted separately. I have addressed your first question in my posted answer. You might consider posting your second question separately.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The questions are closely related so I put them together. I will do an another post.

Answer (score 3):

It is a mistake to test if a variable is significant and drop it is it is not. By screening this way, you distort your downstream inferences that assume a model to be fit without this kind of screening. In particular for your analysis, the confidence interval and p-value for the marker variable of interest will be wrong.

What you propose is a form of stepwise regression, which Frank Harrell  eviscerates [here](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/). While the link is for a Stata website, the content is unrelated to the particular software used, and the ideas apply more broadly than the  classical linear model framework that seems to be the big concern there.

Comment: The better reference is surely Frank Harrell's book _Regression Modeling Strategies_ book, although the FAQ will be convenient for anyone without access to it.

Comment: I would start with "It is widely considered to be a mistake". I will no doubt get flak for this view, but I think it is a defensible or at least not outrageous scientific strategy to simplify a model if predictor terms turn out to be unnecessary.  From my point of view, P-values and even confidence intervals are at best indications in any case.  The best way to proceed is to be open about what you did and let other people have their go at the data if they want to check or disagree.

Comment: In e.g. medicine and social science it can be important to show that you have tested a large number of possible effects that may be very small or negligible in magnitude, but could be at work. In many other sciences, a good model is a really simple fit that happily ignores minor effects.

Comment: Thank you Dave and Nick for your responses. So if I'm interested in an overall effect of an marker and between the groups and the interaction distorts the effect of a marker it is reasonable to build two models? Considering the fact that this interaction is  not known in the literature.

Comment: You're getting close to asking about what best to do in your scientific context, and whatever it is, it is not my corner of science. In practice in my part of the world testing a hypothesis that no one has and showing that it doesn't hold is not easily publishable.

Comment: The hypothesis has at least a good pathophysiological explanation and maybe it is beside the point, whether if it is publishable. For this research question the overall effect in this population is also of interest, that is why I was struggling with the statistically best way  to proceed.

Answer (score 3):

My sense is that you started out by trying to fit too complex a model for the data that you have. Frank Harrell has extensive [online notes](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/) to accompany his [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) text, which provide valuable guidance for how to build regression models (including survival models) properly.

For a survival model you typically need about 15 *events* (not just participants) per coefficient you are estimating, to fit a model reasonably without overfitting. Furthermore, a large number of coefficients necessarily reduces the power to find any of them to be significant.

If your model has a single marker X, 3 groups in G, and the X-G interaction, you are fitting at least 5 coefficients.* Unless you had on the order of 75 events you probably should not have even attempted such a complex model (without penalization). Without the interaction you would be down to only 3 coefficients.

An alternate approach, if you don't care about the association of G with outcome except insofar as the associations of X with outcome might depend on the group, would be to set up a Cox model stratified by group and an interaction of X with the strata. Then you are down again to only 3 coefficients to evaluate your "hypothesis that marker X has different effect in groups G."

There's also a question about how you are evaluating whether "the effect of a marker is significant." In a model with an interaction, you can't evaluate that significance solely from the individual coefficient for X (as I often see attempted in questions on this site). That's only for the association of X with outcome *in the reference category of G*.

To evaluate the  association of X with outcome in the presence of interactions, you need to evaluate all of the coefficients involving it *together*, as in the "Type II" Wald tests provided by the `Anova()` function in the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) or the `anova()` function specific to objects in Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) (*not* the basic `anova()` function in R).

Assuming that the model with interactions was significantly different from a null model and you can demonstrate (e.g., by bootstrapping) that the model wasn't overfit, you have identified some combination of predictors associated with outcome. Lack of significance of particular predictors means that you aren't yet able to tell exactly which specific combinations. What you might do in that case is to present the results as you found them for the two models sequentially, but to acknowledge that the *p*-values in the model without interactions, which you developed after seeing the initial results, aren't valid--as the answer from @Dave (+1) rightly points out. That will allow your work to serve as a guide to others (and you) for later exploration.

---

*In general, I'm skeptical of survival models that omit covariates that are known to be associated with outcome, so these counts of coefficients are ideally underestimates, as are the numbers of events needed. There's a big risk that what you "discover" about X or the groups is just that they are associated with some other well-known outcome-associated factor that you left out of the model.

Comment: Would you say that the advice to have ~15 events per coefficient is the same whether the coefficient is a main effect or an interaction. Intuitively, I expect that interactions have smaller effects and therefore would need more events?

Comment: @dipetkov you are probably right in terms of getting high precision of the estimate of an interaction. The rule of thumb has more to do with minimizing the risk of overfitting and getting unrealistically low standard standard errors due to vagaries of the data sample. I might have elided that distinction in the answer.